# python tkinter button command does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program in python tkinter which user first have to login, then the first page is closed and new one opens with some buttons inside.

button must change it's color and text on click but it does not do anything

```
from tkinter import *


def button_clicked(button):
    Button(button).configure(bg="red", text="not Active")


def open_setting_page():
    loginPage.destroy()
    setting_page = Tk()
    setting_page.title("Setting")
    setting_page.geometry("400x300")

    b2 = Button(setting_page, text="Active", height=5, width=10, bg="green",command=lambda:button_clicked(b2)).grid(row=0, column=0)
    b3 = Button(setting_page, text="Active", height=5, width=10, bg="green",command=lambda:button_clicked(b3)).grid(row=0, column=1)
    setting_page.mainloop()






#program starts here

loginPage = Tk()
loginPage.title("Security System")
loginPage.geometry("400x300")
Label(text="\n\n\n\n").pack()
l1 = Label(text="Enter Password:")
l1.pack()

password_entry = Entry()
password_entry.insert(0, "Enter Your Password...")
password_entry.pack()
b1 = Button(text="Login", command=open_setting_page)
b1.pack()
loginPage.mainloop()
```

I want the buttons color and text be changed on click but noting happens when I click it.

Comment: `button_clicked()` is creating a brand-new Button, calling `.config()` on it uselessly, and then throwing the new Button away.  If you want to affect the Button that was passed as the `button` parameter, do `button.config(...)`.

Comment: Oh - also you need to assign your actual Buttons to `b2`/`b3`, rather than the result of calling `.grid()` on them.  Do the geometry management as a separate statement.

Comment: Also no matter how many `tk.Tk` windows you have, you only need 1 `.mainloop()` so you can remove the `setting_page.mainloop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two problems in this code:

1. in `open_setting_page()` -> the variables `b2` and `b3` become `None` because `Button(XXX).grid()` returns `None` -> lets separate the button creation and the grid placement into 2 steps.
2. in `button_clicked(button)` function -> `Button(button).configure` is wrong. it should be `button.configure(XX)` to get hold of the button that you gave to the function.

Here is how these two functions could look like:

```
def button_clicked(button):
    button.configure(bg="red", text="not Active")


def open_setting_page():
    loginPage.destroy()
    setting_page = Tk()
    setting_page.title("Setting")
    setting_page.geometry("400x300")

    b2 = Button(setting_page, text="Active", height=5, width=10, bg="green", command=lambda: button_clicked(b2))
    b3 = Button(setting_page, text="Active", height=5, width=10, bg="green", command=lambda: button_clicked(b3))
    b2.grid(row=0, column=0)
    b3.grid(row=0, column=1)

    setting_page.mainloop()
```